# selenium scraper get empty list with Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am scraping price data on the website: https://fbx.freightos.com/ .

This is the code below:

> from selenium import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.edge.service
> import Service from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
>
> s = Service(e_driver_path)
> driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s)
>
> elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
> `/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/span`)
>
> content = "".join([element.text for element in elements])
>
> print(content)

the problem is the result. It is an empty list.
As planned, it should be the "Current FBX" and the result looks like "$3,540".
Please help.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Even this Xpath works - `//div[text()='Current FBX']/following-sibling::span`...

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait for required data

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

fbx = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[.='Current FBX']/following-sibling::span[normalize-space()]"))).text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `webdriverwait()` and wait for visibility of element located and following css selector

```
driver.get("https://fbx.freightos.com/")
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".row.bottom-xs.between-xs div:nth-of-type(1)>div"))).text)
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".row.bottom-xs.between-xs div:nth-of-type(1)>span"))).text)
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

This xpath will directly target the price web element.
Try fetching this after some wait as mentioned by @KunduK

```
//div[contains(text(),'Current FBX')]/parent::div/span
```

Comment: How do you find the xpath you provide? I use edge browser and it only provide two copy option: 'copy xpath' and 'copy full xpath'. Both option does not lead to the xpath you provide.

Comment: The xpaths can be customized as per requirement. You can learn how to make efficient and unique xpaths from various resources. It's a useful skill.

Answer (score 0):

```
//span[@class='styled__Value-sc-1puuh0x-8 hIASbB']
```

You can also use xpath like this. simplicity is best

Comment: Simplicity is good but... This XPath is not unique as it fetches both span for "Current FBX" and "Volatility", so might be not the best approach. Also the class name gives no information about the object so one should avoid such uninformative locators

Comment: you're right Volatility overlooked

Comment: Absolute XPath is not better. But if you post the 4th answer it should be at least not worse than previous 3. I see no improvements in your answer

Comment: You can use any of these answers. They all give results.